# Overwrite with empty string in a file read line Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file

I am working a script that will remove text at a given spot that is separated with xFE with the text identifiers as x14.

Here is an example of a line:

```
þþ \xFE þþ \xFE þþ \xFE þþ \xFE þþ \xFE þþ \xFE þþ \xFE þþ \xFE þþ
```

(Note: The xFE character will not display properly. Sorry.)

What I want is to get the nth þþ. I have already split it on the \xFE and can check the value, but what I want to do is to empty the value between the þþ.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, what I am doing is reading a file and at the nTh position on a line in that file I want to replace the contents surrounded by the specified þþ characters. It is a CSV file that use the \xFE and \x14 characters. What I am trying to do is split the line at the \xFE and then get the value between the \x14 chars then overwrite that value in the file.

Comment: did you already try split(), assign, then join()?  It would be useful to know what you've considered and tried and why they didn't work so that proposed answers don't suggest a solution that you've already had issues with.

Comment: an example of what should result from the above line would also be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the string 'aaZbbZccZddZeeZff' so that it is easier to identify the nth item rather than the characters you are using.

As a regular expression, to remove the fourth item,

```
my $data = 'aaZbbZccZddZeeZff';
$data =~ s/((?:..Z){3})../\1/;
print $data;
print "\n";
```

This returns the string 'aaZbbZccZZeeff' (note the doubled delimiter - though this is easy to fix by adding the delimiter to the match).

If you already have split this into a list, it is also possible to use splice to remove an item from the list and then reconstruct the string.

```
my $data = 'aaZbbZccZddZeeZff';
my @data = split('Z',$data);
splice(@data,3,1);
print $data;
print "\n";
```

This prints 'aaZbbZccZeeZff'.